# C++ hash function which takes a seed

Tags: c++, function, hash

Update - What library can give me a  good hash function that takes a seed in c++?

Comment: Contender for today's most incomprehensible question?

Comment: 100 hash functions, or 100 hashes?  Does this deal with cryptography?

Comment: `template<int N> int hash(char *p) { return *p^N; }`

Comment: Create one hash function, then add `i` to the result, where `i` ranges from 1 to 100. One hundred unique hash functions.

Comment: "100 unique hash functions"... This sounds like you are trying to implement Cuckoo Hashing. If that's it, you can just use one hash function and use a different seed or add a different constant every time. I've tried that, works perfectly well.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a hash function that I can seed.  Any suggestions

Comment: I'm tempted to press the downvote button

Comment: You can seed _every_ hash function by feeding it a number or string or whatever before calculating the actual hash. In the case of Cuckoo Hashing, you can even use a random inital "constant" if you use a hash like for example DJB2. Normally that would be totally no go because constants in hash functions are fine tuned, and tampering with them means very bad mojo. For CH that does not matter a lot, you can just throw it away if it is really too bad (and, while generally getting bad hash function playing with parameters is easy, getting one that is too bad to be usable for CH happens rarely).

Comment: Be careful using the std::hash<int> because in many implementations it's the identity function which will not work with the workaround of @Damon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like a [Perfect Hash Generator](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=perfect%20hash%20generator), and not something like a [List of Hash Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions), written to share a common interface which is then melodramatically selected at runtime.

*EDIT*:  now that the question is clarified, only you can evaluate which is "the best" perfect hash generator for your application written in C++.

Comment: Silly auto-correct.  Although I like melodramatic over programmatic in this regard.

Comment: A perfect hash generator is exactly what I'm looking for.  ( I just didn't know the name for it)

Comment: That's hilarious. I was trying to imagine a program getting all worked up over which function to choose.

Comment: The key phrase was "strings that are deterministically chosen".  It would be better to put the number 100 closer to the word `strings` to avoid confusion by others.